# How to detect long click on entity in a-frame scene?

Tags: javascript, mobile, aframe, webvr

I want to listen to long clicks on objects (lets say a two seconds click) to give my users a second form of interaction other than single click.

**What I've tried**

I've accomplished this on desktop browsers by implementing an a-frame component that listens to mouse events. It listens for the `mousedown` event and then sets a timeout of two seconds before simply changing the color of the clicked entity. I also have a `mouseup` event listener to cancel the timeout if the mouse button is release after two seconds.

This works as expected on desktop but does not on mobile. For this I've tried with an additional event listener for the `touchstart` event but it's just not working.

**Steps to reproduce**

Here I show a snippet with my code working on desktop, if you click and hold the yellow box for two seconds it'll change its color to red. If you release the mouse before two seconds the timeout is cancelled and no color change is made (well, when you click the yellow box and then drag&drop the cursor away of it, the timeout is not cancelled, even when you release the mouse button before two seconds, I wonder if for this drag&drop cancellation I need to listen to a different event and not `mouseup`).

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  
  <script>
    AFRAME.registerComponent('long-click', {
      init: function() {
        var data = this.data;
        var el = this.el;

        var pressTimer = null;
        var longpress = false;

        el.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
          if (pressTimer !== null) {
            clearTimeout(pressTimer);
            pressTimer = null;
          }

          if (longpress) {
            return false;
          }

          console.log('mouse up');
        }); // addEventListener('mouseup');
        
        // listens for mousedown and changes entity color after two seconds
        el.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
          console.log("mouse down");

          longpress = false;

          pressTimer = setTimeout(function(){
            console.log("long click");
            AFRAME.utils.entity.setComponentProperty(el, 'material.color', 'red');

            longpress = true;
          },2000);

        });
      } // end of init
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <a-scene>
    <a-box long-click position="0 2 -2" color='yellow'></a-box>

    <a-camera>
      <a-entity cursor="fuse: false" position="0 0 -1" geometry="primitive: ring; radius-inner: 0.01; radius-outer: 0.03;" material="color: black; shader: flat"></a-entity>
    </a-camera>
  </a-scene>
</body>
```

I've tried listening for `touchstart` event but get nothing. What should I do to get this same functionality for mobiles when you are in VR mode?

**Observations**

I'm developing on a Mac and testing on mobile with Chrome for Android in a Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge Plus.

Comment: What is logged in console when you try on Chrome for Android?

Comment: Well, when I load my app a few warnings and the next error message: `Error loading online DPBP` 

Then it shows the logs for the `mousedown` event but not when I touch the screen but until I stop touching it, like this: I touch and hold the screen and nothing happens, I stop touching it and both the `mousedown` and `mouseup` messages appear... which is a problem because it fires the `mouseup` event, so my timeout is started and cancelled at the same time.